# Having Trouble Accessing the Value of a Score stored in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

[image]I'm having issues when trying to access the value of a score that is stored in the `localStorage` from a variable that is equal to how many questions the user gets right. I thought it would be exactly the same as setting the value but most likely I've done something wrong, and I lack the experience to figure it out..

I Want to display the User's score on the screen's scoreboard where the complete button is. I easily set the score into the `localStorage` with the `setItem(users, score)` line, but it seems `getItem(score)` doesn't work when I want to set `displayUser.textContent = getItem(score)`.

I've tried a lot of different ways, and I always get `null`. I also noticed every time I submit a new entry to the scoreboard, the key's name keeps the last entries name and stores it on the end.

I'd love to fix this myself, but after making no progress or any leads for 3 hours, I think I might ask for some help. I reused and changed a lot of this code from a class activity in my boot camp so the complete button is just there to remove entries while in development.

Here's all of the relevant JavaScript hopefully

```
//Variables to Shorten text
var startButton = document.getElementById('startbtn')
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextbtn')
var finishEarlyButton = document.getElementById('finishEarlyBtn')
var introSection = document.getElementById('intro')
var questionSection = document.getElementById('Question-Section')
var questionElement = document.getElementById('question')
var answerButtons = document.getElementById('Answer-Section')
var scoreboard = document.getElementById('Score-Container')
var userScore = document.getElementById('Score')
var seeScoreBtn = document.getElementById('seeScore')
var restartBtn = document.getElementById('restart')
var finishbtn = document.getElementById('finishbtn')
var userAnswer = ""

var shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex
var score = 0

var userName = document.getElementById('scoreboard-input')
var leaderboard = document.getElementById('leaderboard')
var leaderboardUsers = document.getElementById('leaderboardUsers')

var users = [];

init();

function init() {
    var storedUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Users"))
    if (storedUsers !== null) {
        users = storedUsers;

        renderUsers();
    }
}

function renderUsers() {
    leaderboardUsers.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];

        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = user;
        li.setAttribute("data-index", i);

        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = "Complete";

        var displayUser = document.createElement("button");
        displayUser.textContent = (localStorage.getItem(score));
        //displayUser.textContent = "test";
        console.log(localStorage.getItem(users.value))

        li.appendChild(displayUser);
        li.appendChild(button);
        leaderboardUsers.appendChild(li);
    }
}

function storeUsers() {
    //localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
    //localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(users), JSON.stringify(score));
    localStorage.setItem(users, score);
}

leaderboard.addEventListener("submit", function() {
    event.preventDefault();

    var userText = userName.value.trim();
    var userCorrectAnswers = score.value;

    if (userText === "") {
        return
    }

    //users.push(userCorrectAnswers);
    users.push(userText);
    userName.value = "";

    storeUsers()
    renderUsers()
    console.log
})

leaderboardUsers.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var element = event.target;

    if (element.matches("button") === true) {
        var index = element.parentElement.getAttribute("data-index");
        users.splice(index, 1);

        storeUsers();
        renderUsers();
    }
})
```

Let me know if the html or rest of JS is needed!

Answer (score 1):

Well just by looking at the code we can see that you're accessing it via

```
var storedUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Users"))
```

and storing it via

```
localStorage.setItem(users, score);
```

With the way you're accessing it, you would set it via

```
localStorage.setItem("Users", JSON.stringify(users));
```

It is case-sensitive, which is probably why your attempt of using the key `users` didn't work in your first comment under your `storeUsers` function.

Comment: Yeah in terms of the case sensitive stuff , its just my messy naming of variables. i have user, storedUsers, users etc... i need to work on having easier to read code.. Thanks a lot for the reply man

Answer (score 1):

You are not using localStorage `setItem` correctly.

```
localStorage.setItem(users, score);
```

Both arguments to `setItem()` must be strings, with the first argument a key, and the second argument the value to store. Your first argument is an array (the data type of your second argument is unclear).

Typical value of a `setItem` first argument: 'usersScores'.

```
localStorage.setItem('usersScores', JSON.stringify(score));
```

Note the use of `JSON.stringify()` to convert `score` to a string, because localStorage only stores data in string form.

You are also not using `getItem` correctly:

```
localStorage.getItem(score)
```

`getItem` must be called with the key used in `setItem`:

```
localStorage.getItem('userScores')
```

And since `score` was saved as a string, you need to convert it back when you read it from localStorage:

```
score = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userScores'))
```

How to use `localStorage` is explained clearly in MDN web docs [Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: Hey i appreciate your reply! turns out all i had to do was "localStorage.getItem(users)" to access the score value so the code is doing everything i want. Next time i use the Local Storage i'll use the the functions you mentioned. Cheers

Comment: @ChrisAMK While that fix got your code working, it's doubtful that it's working as you want. Your key is a list of user names, your score is a number. Wouldn't you want a key for each user name, so you can have a score for each user?

Comment: sorry im still getting used to the wording of everything, so the code was never broken but i was having trouble accessing the value of the key which is set to the score of the user. i can now get the value and display on the screen but things are really confusing when i try to add a second score onto the scoreboard. I know it's got something to do with when i add a new Li, the Key's name carries over the previous one.
Key
Chris
Chris,Jake
Chris,Jake, Harry

It appears i do have a key for each user name, it's just not setting the way i want, ill try post screenshots

Answer (score 1):

This is a lot of code to sift through but setting and getting items requires string key-names and stringified values:

```
localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(score))
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'))
```

This way you should have the same data before and after setting to `localStorage`.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply, I actually figured it out on my own but your reply is the closest to what i ended up doing. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem @ChrisAMK